# SQL Oracle return only max(value) of column value

Tags: sql, oracle

My data looks like this.

[image]

The output I am looking to see is:

[image]

Here is a query I wrote which is not quite there yet but I know the logic of what I should be doing. I need to take the max value of column(rate) of the same vehicle_size and competitor. This could be written in a better way so I would appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction.

Below is my query:

`SELECT RENTAL_DATE, OUTBOUND, INBOUND 
     CASE
     WHEN Competitor = 'kay' AND VEHICLE_SIZE= 'Small' THEN MAX(RATE)
     WHEN COMPETITOR = 'lola'  AND VEHICLE SIZE = 'Small'THEN MAX(RATE)
     WHEN Competitor = 'kay' AND VEHICLE_SIZE= 'Large' THEN MAX(RATE)
     WHEN COMPETITOR = 'lola'  AND VEHICLE SIZE = 'Large'THEN MAX(RATE)
     ELSE 'RATE'
     END AS RATE
     FROM FORMATTED2018AND2019DATA;`

Second query:

`select  Rental_date, outbound, inbound, vehicle_size, 
       max(rate) where competitor='lola' and vehicle_size = 'small' OR 'large'
       max(Rate)where competitor ='kay' and vehicle_size = 'small' OR 'large'
       from table2 
        group by 
        Rental_date, outbound, inbound, vehicle_size,`

Comment: You said `I need to take the max value of column(rate) of the same vehicle_size and competitor.` What about other columns value do you want in your output?

Comment: Sorry, the rest of the column would be the same as well.

Comment: Then if you want all only max value of column `rate` for each group of all others column, you could simply use aggregate function as in @fa06's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below -

```
select  Rental_date, competitor,outbound, inbound, vehicle_size, 
        max(rate) 
        from table2 
        group by 
        Rental_date, competitor,outbound, inbound, vehicle_size
```